# rviz crash using cartesian path plan

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

iam getting this message

```
[ INFO] [1631544537.675079635]: Computed Cartesian path with 74 points (followed 100.000000% of requested trajectory)
[ INFO] [1631544537.675303283]: Achieved 100.000000 % of Cartesian path
[ INFO] [1631544538.675434715]: Didn't receive robot state (joint angles) with recent timestamp within 1 seconds.
Check clock synchronization if your are running ROS across multiple machines!
[ERROR] [1631544538.675464938]: Failed to fetch current robot state
[rviz_robotik_18323_2580941928133169340-10] process has died [pid 18403, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/melodic/lib/rviz/rviz -d /home/robotik/akinrobotics/RoboticArm/robotic-arm/robotkol_ws/src/robot_arm_v4/launch/moveit.rviz __name:=rviz_robotik_18323_2580941928133169340 __log:=/home/robotik/.ros/log/93d00fb6-149c-11ec-9b7e-d45d6422df12/rviz_robotik_18323_2580941928133169340-10.log].
log file: /home/robotik/.ros/log/93d00fb6-149c-11ec-9b7e-d45d6422df12/rviz_robotik_18323_2580941928133169340-10*.log
```

then rviz shutdown

only i see this message using "cartesian path". but not always giving error, sometimes working good but sometimes crash.

RViz version 1.13.18 (melodic).

need help, thenk you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386416/rviz-crash-using-cartesian-path-plan/) by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2021-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found where the problem is

*the problem does not always occur, it happens sometimes, it does not occur when I do not use cartesian, it occurs sometimes when I use cartesian.*

problem occured when i use;

```
  <include file="$(find robot_arm_v4)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)" />
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)" />
    <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="$(arg use_sim_time)"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="$(arg headless)"/>
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find robot_arm_v4)/launch/world.world"/>
  </include>
```

no problem;

```
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)" />
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)" />
    <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="$(arg use_sim_time)"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="$(arg headless)"/>
  </include>
```

---

Originally posted by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) with karma: 31 on 2021-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-14**:
I guess you don't need world.world :) Glad you found a solution.

**Comment by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) on 2021-09-14**:
i use world.world for

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.5">
  <world name="default">
    <include>
      <uri>model://sun</uri>
    </include>
    <shadows>0</shadows>
    <gravity>0 0 0</gravity>
    <magnetic_field>0 0 0</magnetic_field>
  </world>
</sdf>
```

thenk you so much